# How to add PATH more than one values in Environment variable?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> Is this correct way of adding PATH to env setup

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\Workspace\BS4SVN\BS4SVN-v.1.33.0\ant\bin;D:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin
```

Comment: Yes, Correct only. Are you getting any error here?

Comment: I am not able to build one project using ant

Comment: isn't there a missing colon in the end?

Comment: Can you update the Question with error log?

Answer (score 2):

you can add more than one value and separate them with ';' it works for me

Answer (score -2):

Yes correct. you can add these lines to existing path variable.

Comment: The question: "How to add PATH more than one values in Environment variable?" - can't be answered by "yes" ;)